# How to render an ANSI text coloring on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, posix

I have some strings with beautiful colors that work nicely in Linux terminal:

```
"violets are \e[31;1mgreen\e[0m"
```

However, I would like to somehow display these colors on my website (ie. in this case make "green" have a red color). I am aware that it is not directly supported, but I am looking for possibly the simplest way to achieve it. I don't mind using some already existing JS solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just using a replace filter and custom CSS.

You could turn `\e[31;1m` into `<span style="color:red">`
And then turn `\e[0m` into `</span>`

Then you can just use the replace function in your preference of JS or PHP. Or, you could just replace it manually.

Comment: The problem with search&replace is that in ANSI coloring the "color tags" don't need to be closed.

Comment: That's an easy fix, all you have to do is then check for a closing tag for each color tag, and if none is found, check for another color tag, and if no closing tag or different color tag is found, then just append it to the end of the string.